# What is the significance of @nestjs/schematics? Do we need the package even after creation of an NestJs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Can we remove the following dependancy once we created the Nest App with CLI?

I'm working on a legacy project, it seems the @nestjs/schematics package is unused.
I'm not sure about it's significance as there isn't much content available on internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@nestjs/schematics` holds the blueprints for the `nest g` commands. They're what determine how to build the modules and services via the Nest CLI. If you aren't using the `nest generate` command, then yes you can remove the package. It should be a dev dep anyways so it shouldn't impact production either way.

Comment: That does give some insight about the package, thanks for sharing!